# MPEG2VIDEOINFO to SPS & PPS NAL Units

Tags: windows, video, h.264

Running on Windows OS, I have the h264 configuration set as MPEG2VIDEOINFO struct ( C++ ), I need to derive the SPS & PPS NAL Units **before** the first compressed sample is generated, is there any open source I can use to have that done, preferably a compact solution such that I can cut & paste into my project...

Answer (score 1):

This is explained very clearly [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808(v=vs.85).aspx) .

> If cbSequenceHeader is greater than zero, dwSequenceHeader is the start of a byte array containing SPS and PPS NALUs, delimited by 2-byte length fields, all in network byte order (big-endian). It is possible to have both SPS and PPS, only one of these types, or none. The actual type of each NALU can be determined by examining the nal_unit_type field of the NALU itself.

Writing the code to extract the lengths of the SPS and PPS should not take you more than a few minutes.

Comment: I need to generate the SPS & PPS, not read them as the latter mandate encoding to start and my intention was to have the SPS & PPS before-hand, anyhow, it appears that the decoder i am working with is OK w/ getting the SPS&PPS on the first packet, ( after streaming has started ), so I have this tackled.